# React Redux infinite loop update - Updated with combineReducers started the problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Ok so i'll try to sum it up. I've modified my code to have 2 reducers instead of 1 (for better reading) and i started getting an infinite loop.

The redux props seem to keep updating, however there's no change in them.

This is my reducer file.

```
import { ADD_LISTITEM } from "../constants/action-types.jsx";
import { SET_SPOTOKEN } from '../constants/action-types.jsx';
import { SET_LISTVIEW } from '../constants/action-types.jsx';
import { CHECK_SPOTOKEN } from '../constants/action-types.jsx';
import { SET_FORMPANEL } from '../constants/action-types.jsx';
import { SET_FORMPANELTYPE } from '../constants/action-types.jsx';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'


const initialState = {
    listItems: [],
    spoToken: '',
    listView: "All Items",
    checkToken: "200",
    showNotice: true,
    //showFormPanel: false,
    //formPanelType: ''
};

const listState = {
    showFormPanel: false,
    formPanelType: ''
}
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_LISTITEM:
            return { ...state, listItems: [...state.listItems, action.payload] };
        case SET_SPOTOKEN:
            return { ...state, spoToken: action.payload };
        case SET_LISTVIEW:
            return { ...state, listView: action.payload };
        case CHECK_SPOTOKEN:
            return { ...state, checkToken: action.payload };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const listReducer = (state = listState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_FORMPANEL:
            return { ...state, showFormPanel: action.payload };
        case SET_FORMPANELTYPE:
            return { ...state, formPanelType: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    rootReducer,
    listReducer
});
export default allReducers;
```

Any idea why this might cause a problem?

Edited with Redux State ->

```
{
    root: { … }, newItem: { … }, forms: { … }
} forms: {
    $form: { … }, newItem: { … }
} newItem: { Title: "", ItemID: "", OfferingID: "", DeliveryModality: "", Status: "", … }
root: listReducer: {
    showFormPanel: false, formPanelType: ""
} rootReducer: {
    listItems: Array(4), spoToken: { … }, listView: "All Items", checkToken: "200", showNotice: true
}
```

Puttin the above into words since it looks kinda messed up.

State contains -> `forms`, `newItem`, `root`. Root contains `listReducer` and `rootReducer`.

FIXED: only 1 `combineReducers` allowed.

Apparently since i didnt have different reducers before adding this one i had another `combineReducers` in my redux-form file. I assume that was the problem (having 2 `combineReducers`) because it seems to work fine after modifying it.

Comment: Why do you have two `root`s, `newItem`s, and `form`s? Is that just a copy paste error?

Comment: That's a copy paste error, nothing is duplicate (names are a bit ambiguos since i wanted to test everything before renaming properly). The only 2 objects with similar names are root & rootReducer (`rootReducer` is a child of `root`).

Edit: wait, it actually isnt a copy paste error, gotta check this out.

Comment: Dante, it's best if you don't title and compose your question as though we're all in some conversational loop. It should stand on its own feet for newcomers, as well. I suggest revising and cleaning up irrelevant comments (or incorporating them into your post).